# Add timestamp for each line on the df output command?

Tags: linux, date, aix, linux-disk-free

I would like to add the date for each line of the `df` output.

I tried:

```
df -m | awk '{print `date +%Y-%m`";"$1";"$2";"$3 }'
```

... but it doesn't work.

How can I add the date?

Comment: is this for [tag:linux] or for [tag:aix]?

Comment: AIX and Linux :)

Comment: I'd suggest [Dave Cross's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271639/7552) should be portable over those platforms. Does `df -m` give the same output on Linux and AIX?

Comment: You may want to consider the `-P` option to `df` to give a portable/consistent output format.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this way:

```
df -m | awk -v dt=$(date "+%Y-%m") '{print dt "::", $0}'
```

We use `-v dt=$(date "+%Y-%m")` to execute date command in shell and pass it to `awk` in an argument `dt`.

If you want only first 3 columns from `df` command output then use:

```
df -m | awk -v dt=$(date "+%Y-%m") '{print dt, $1, $2, $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
df -m | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m"), $0}'
```

And here is the output from the command above:

```
$ df -m | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m"), $0}'
2019-10 Filesystem                     1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
2019-10 devtmpfs                            9852      0      9852   0% /dev
2019-10 tmpfs                               9871    132      9740   2% /dev/shm
2019-10 tmpfs                               9871      2      9869   1% /run
2019-10 /dev/mapper/fedora_canvas-root     50141  14731     32834  31% /
2019-10 tmpfs                               9871      1      9871   1% /tmp
2019-10 /dev/sda5                            976    243       667  27% /boot
2019-10 /dev/mapper/fedora_canvas-home   1277155 217435    994777  18% /home
2019-10 tmpfs                               1975     63      1912   4% /run/user/1000
$
```

And here is an alternative version, printing just the 3 columns you wanted on the OP:

```
df -m | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m"), $1, $2, $3}' | column -t
```

And the corresponding output:

```
$ df -m | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m"), $1, $2, $3}' | column -t
2019-10  Filesystem                      1M-blocks  Used
2019-10  devtmpfs                        9852       0
2019-10  tmpfs                           9871       132
2019-10  tmpfs                           9871       2
2019-10  /dev/mapper/fedora_canvas-root  50141      14731
2019-10  tmpfs                           9871       1
2019-10  /dev/sda5                       976        243
2019-10  /dev/mapper/fedora_canvas-home  1277155    217435
2019-10  tmpfs                           1975       63
$
```

Comment: `strftime()` is a GNU awk extension. Available on AIX?

Comment: @glennjackman, it is a good point and must be taken into consideration by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution.

```
df -m | perl -MPOSIX=strftime -alpe '$_ = strftime("%Y-%M ", localtime) . "@F[0..2]"'
```

Command line options:

- -M : Load the`strftime()` function from the POSIX module
- -a : Autosplit the input records on whitespace into `@F`
- -l : Remove newlines from input and add them to output
- -p : Put each input record into `$_`, execute code and then print `$_`
- -e : Run this code for each input record

The code updates `$_` by concatenating the date (`strftime("%Y-%M ", localtime)`) with the first three columns (`@F[0 .. 2]`) of the input record.

Comment: You'll want `'$_ = join(";", strftime("%Y-%m", localtime), @F[0..2])'` to get OP's desired output.